# Ler valores da porta serial usando Pyserial

Tags: python, serial, nagios

Criei um *plugin* para monitorar um sensor de presença no Arduino para o Nagios. O *plugin* ler valores da porta serial no Arduino. O problema é que o Nagios não deixa o *plugin* em execução, ele executa pega os valores e encerra. Dessa forma ele não lê os dados corretamente.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
import serial

    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=0)
    while True:
        if state == "0":
          print "OK - Sem Alertas"
          sys.exit(0)
        elif (str(ser.read()) == '2'):
          print "WARNING " 
          sys.exit(1)
        elif (str(ser.read()) == '1'):
          print "CRITICAL - Intrusos Detectados" 
          sys.exit(2)
        else:
          print "UKNOWN - Parametro Desconhecido"
          sys.exit(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece porque você está fazendo chamadas a `sys.exit([arg])`. Isso faz com o que o programa encerre. Remova as chamadas de `sys.exit([arg])` e faça os testes novamente.

Referência: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit